# Drupal 7 - Blocks: how do you specify it a list of pages except certain pages?

Tags: drupal-7, block

I created a block that I want to appear on these paths:

example.com/sample/1   
example.com/sample/2 
 example.com/sample/3
   example.com/sample/4 
 example.com/sample/6

However, I don't want it to appear on:

example.com/sample/5

Under the visibility setting for the block, I can select show block on "Only the listed pages"
and enter something like /sample/*

Howevever, how do I tell it not to show up in /sample/5 without typing out all other paths individually?  Is there an "except" or "not" indicator somehow like how the * indicates all?

Answer (score 2):

Use [the context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) to handle the placement of your block. It allows you to specify which paths the block should display on, as well as which it should not (by starting the path with a ~)

For example, in your context you can specify your paths like so:
sample/*
~sample/5

this tells drupal to display your block on all paths that match "sample/*" except for "sample/5"

Answer (score 1):

There is only two ways of getting the fine tuning you need:

1. You type one by one all the URLs you want to include/exclude
2. You go for the perfectly customizable php code mode.

Maybe you should try Context module http://drupal.org/project/context and see if the more complex, configurable options it provide serve your purpose/solve your problem.

PD. My first answer completely missed the point, i was thinking on views... sorry!

Comment: Where do you add filters to blocks?  That would be cool, but I hope we're talking about the same thing.  Under Structure > Blocks > Configure block > Visibility Settings > Pages I don't see any blue link or anything where I can add new filters.  I just see 2 radio buttons "All pages except those listed" or "Only the listed pages"

Comment: juum ok ok, i completely missed your question! i'm correcting my answer!

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thanks for your answer (and for correcting it!) Wish there were some kind of simple operator to indicate "all x-pages except y-pages"  Back to typing things out one by one. :(  (don't know enough php)

Comment: Anyway, you should take a look at Context module http://drupal.org/project/context It will probably help you get your results without typing a single php-code line :)